# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal - UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to save a file in which I have some credentials. In order not to leave passwords in clear in the file, I encrypted them with the `pycrypto` module. But when I try to save my file with the result strings, I have an error:

- I had 1st to save my file as UTF-8 because of the strange characters I receive (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)`
- but then I still face some issues: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` (for instance on string `'tý}DŠÇ{÷­*6Ù·®'`) when I run my code via F5 in IDLE (saving is ok).

Note that this string can be used normally in IDLE shell:

```
>>> s = 'tý}DŠÇ{÷­*6Ù·®'
>>> s
't\xfd}\x7fD\x8a\xc7{\x17\xf7\xad*6\xd9\xb7\xae'
>>>
```

Can you please help ? Thanks !

**EDIT:** this may not be clear: this string is in a python program, I'm not trying to write it in an external file.
Another thing: looks like the character that seems to be causing the error (`\x7f` in hexa) was removed by the SO interpreter.

Comment: please paste the code where you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `zlib` instead (no real encryption, but the passwords are no longer left in clear) which produces ASCII chars so no problem now... Of course that does not solve my initial problem, but I spent already too much time trying to solve it. Thanks Ignacio for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be treating encrypted data as a string unless you have explicitly asked for a string format, e.g. hexadecimal digits; files should be opened in binary mode, and such data should not be printed to the console.

Comment: The thing is: I don't try to print it, this was just a test. This string is just a string in my program (in my global variables), that I just can't run because of this error.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You're goofing up elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, so let me describe what I do: I have a python program in which this string is written. Encoding of the file is `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Saving is ok, but when I press F5, I have this error.

Comment: I was in case a point was unclear to you: I assure you it happens, believe it or not.

Comment: I don't doubt that *something* happens. But you are wrong about the cause.